# Drillthrough parameter value from a Lookup()

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Hello I am trying to pass a Looked-Up Value as drillthrough parameter to a subreport. I have two Datasets **Dataset1** and **Dataset2**. My tablix looks like this

```
=Fields!Number.Value 'Column1 expression (Dataset1)
=Lookup(Fields!Number.Value, Fields!NumberKey.Value, Fields!Order.Value, "Dataset2") 'Column2 expression (Dataset2)

Column1    Column2
1          123
2          678
```

Now I want to use the value from Column2 as drillthrough parameter. Under the option *Action -> Go to report* I already tried different approaches, but none would work. For the parameter passing value I tried:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Number.Value, Fields!NumberKey.Value, Fields!Order.Value, "Dataset2")
=Lookup(Fields!Number.Value, Fields!NumberKey.Value, Fields!Order.Value, "Dataset2").Value
=Lookup(Fields!Number.Value, Fields!NumberKey.Value, Fields!Order.Value, "Dataset2").UniqueName
=ReportItems!OrderTextbox.Value
=ReportItems!OrderTextbox.UniqueName
```

Is this even possible? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: your first or 4th options should work fine. I've just tested with a simple setup and setting the parameter value on the action to either the lookup expression or to the report item value worked as expected. Try building a simple subreport that just accepts a text parameter, then adding a textbox that shows this parameter value. Then set your action to open that report, that way you can see what is getting passed. If you are getting errors, please edit your question to show them. I tested using SSRS 2016 but I'm sure I've done this on 2008 too.

Comment: I also use SSRS 2016. I already had a test setup, to check if the subreport will be loeaded. I tested it with a test dataset where I loaded in some **OrderValues**. This worked fine and the subreport was shown (I also placed the textbox you mentioned). So I tested it with my tablix from above where the lookup is included. Well the subreport gets shown but its all empty. The parameter dropdown on top of the subreport is also empty (with the 1st and 4th option)

Comment: Could it be that it is not working, because I can have more matches? I could also perform a **LookupSet()**. For my purpose it didnt matter if I performed a **Lookup** or a **LookupSet**, so I chose the first one.

Comment: and if you open the simple test  report from your tablix what parameter value is being passed in? In term sof having more than one match, that seems like a design issue, lookups should only retrieve a single value, not sure what happens if there are more than one, I suspect it will just find the first but I've not checked the documentation to confirm.

Comment: I found the solution. The names of the parameters (internal) are different, because of the **Lookup**. The name of the parameter I passed is `[OrderDimension].[OrderNumber].&[001234]` the name of the subreport parameter is `[Orders].[OrderNr].&[001234]`. This didnt work, even if the same value existed in both. I solved it when I wrote the passing parameter value like this `="[Orders].[OrderNr].&[" & Lookup(Fields!Number.Value, Fields!NumberKey.Value, Fields!Order.Value, "Dataset2") & "]"`

Comment: Glad to hear you got there in the end.

Comment: How can I mark this question as answered now?

Comment: As my comments didn't really constitute an answer you can just add an answer (based on your last comment) yourself then mark it  as an accepted answer. I'm not sure how much reputation you'll need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The names of the parameters (internal) are different, because of the Lookup. The name of the parameter I passed is

```
[OrderDimension].[OrderNumber].&[001234]
```

the name of the subreport parameter is

```
[Orders].[OrderNr].&[001234]
```

This didnt work, even if the same value existed in both. I solved it when I wrote the passing parameter value like this

```
="[Orders].[OrderNr].&[" & Lookup(Fields!Number.Value, Fields!NumberKey.Value, Fields!Order.Value, "Dataset2") & "]"
```